# How do I initialize the size of a Hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I would like to specify an initial size for my Hash in Ruby.  I know I am going to be adding tens of millions of entries in the hash and a lot of time is wasting rehashing the data every time Ruby decides it needs a larger hash.

Other languages support something like a "reserve" call to pre-size the hash.  Can this be done in Ruby?

Comment: Do you have experimental data indicating that it is too slow, and that rehashing is the cause?

Comment: It's hard to confirm it's rehashing, but every so often, when I add an element to the hash, it takes several orders of magnitude longer that normal.  I assume it is rehashing at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's Hash doesn't have any way to do that.  It should still be relatively performant either way, but you might want to consider other data storage methods, such as a database or key/value store like Memcached or Redis, for data sets of that magnitude.

Comment: ActiveRecord's great for pushing things to a database. Just wondering - what kind of data are you operating on?

Comment: I do data-mining.  I have tables with hundreds of millions of records I need to work on quickly.  Putting things on disk or back in a database would make it WAY too slow.  I use a hash for it's near O(1) performance.  It's hard to beat that.

Comment: @Starkii, You might want to consider showing your schema over on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ and asking for optimization and/or query help. Hundreds of millions of records can still be accessed quickly when the database is set up right. It's all in the indexing.

Comment: Java HashMap is using separate chaining with linked lists, what data structure/algorithm Ruby Hash is using?