# How is Hash in Ruby implemented internally? What data structure/algorithm Hash is using?

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, hashtable

I know in Java language, `HashMap` is the most common used to implement functions like Ruby `Hash`. Java `HashMap` is using data structure named "**separate chaining with linked lists**": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Where can I find the implementation of Ruby hash? What data structure and algorithm Ruby `Hash` are using?

Comment: This is a "teach me Ruby" question, which is off topic on StackOverflow as it is too broad. I recommend following a Ruby tutorial.

Comment: @MarkThomas I have edited my question, it is not about "teach me Ruby, how to use Hash" question, my purpose is try to know what data structure and algorithm Ruby ``Hash`` is using. Could you please help reopen this question?

Comment: If you want an explanation of how it is implemented, try this post from Tealeaf Academy: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-the-hash-works-in-ruby or this excellent sample chapter by Pat Shaughnessy's book, Ruby Under a Microscope: http://patshaughnessy.net/Ruby-Under-a-Microscope-Rough-Draft-May.pdf

Comment: A rewrite of the implementation landed in 2.4. The author explains it nicely in a blog post: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/02/27/towards-faster-ruby-hash-tables/

Answer (score 4):

Please see it in [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/), just select the method, and click link:`click to toggle source`, and it shows you sources.

1. the [`::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) singleton method of [array](/questions/tagged/array):

   ```
                  static VALUE
   rb_ary_s_create(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
   {
       VALUE ary = ary_new(klass, argc);
       if (argc > 0 && argv) {
           ary_memcpy(ary, 0, argc, argv);
           ARY_SET_LEN(ary, argc);
       }

       return ary;
   }
   ```
2. the [`#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) instance method of [array](/questions/tagged/array).
3. the [`::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) singleton method of [hash-table](/questions/tagged/hash-table) (`Hash` class).
4. the [`#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) instance method of [hash-table](/questions/tagged/hash-table) (`Hash` class).

The code means that zero-sized [array](/questions/tagged/array) will be assigned to `arr` variable:

```
arr = []
arr
# => []
```

Default sizes for [array](/questions/tagged/array), and [hash-table](/questions/tagged/hash-table) (`Hash` class) is `0`:

```
# Array
[].size
# => 0
Array.new.size
# => 0

# Hash
{}.size
# => 0
Hash.new.size
# => 0
```

Comment: I think **3** will be `Hash::[]`

Comment: @ArupRakshit thanx, that was copypasta =)

Comment: Hehehe :) I know.. =)

Comment: thanks, so if use something like `arr = Array.new(10000)` if we know the size of the array to avoid re-size operation, but Ruby Hash does not provide any method to initialize hash table size according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719092/how-do-i-initialize-the-size-of-a-hash-in-ruby

Comment: @coderz not exactly, with `Array.new(10000)` you just initialize the `Array` with default values. generally `nil`. but you still can access or set to `arr[10002]`

Comment: got it! i just tested the performance between `arr = Array.new(1000000)` and `arr = []` with `arr << i` which 0 <= i <= 1000000, they show almost same performance.

Comment: @coderz with the `Benchmark`?=)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ you can still do `array[102] = true` after `array = Array.new(100)`

Comment: @Abdo yes, I can: `arr = Array.new(10); arr[12]= 'ewew';  arr
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "ewew"]`

Answer (score 2):

Would these help?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-c-new

`arr = []` is the same as `arr = Array.new(0, nil)` where 0 is the size of the array.

Click on toggle source and scroll down to see the code.

Same for Hash , check the documentation at:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html